# CRM 2011, after saving, fields revert back to invisible

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm new to CRM 2011 so I apologize if the answer is obvious. The entity I made is a form where the user fills out information, some fields are hidden until the meets certain requirements to have them visible.

Example: Were you late? Yes/No
         (hidden until yes is selected)Reason:

I used javascript to make them invisible at the start and then make them visible if the requirements are met. After the user presses the save button, the field "Reason" would go back to being invisible, is there a way to make it stay visible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your JS code?  It sounds like there is some additional logic needed in the onload event code.

Comment: function hideField(fieldName)
{
 Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(fieldName).setVisible(false);
}

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write javascript code in the `onLoad` event to see if the field's values are already in a state that would result in the fields being visible.  After the entity is saved, it reloads itself, incase a plugin happened to edit an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you already attached your function to the attribute onchange event you need to add the following to your onload event:

```
//Will fire all functions connected to the attribute change event
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attribute_name").fireOnChage();
```

Or directory call the function that implements the code i.e.

```
//Will only call the specified function.
ShowHideField();
```

Also you might find it easier to attach to onchange handlers 
directly from onload code instead of the form UI i.e.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attribute_name").addOnChange(ShowHideField);
```

And to summarize:

```
function OnCrmPageLoad() {

    var attrObj = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("attribute_name");
    attrObj.addOnChange(ShowHideField);
    attrObj.fireOnChage(); // OR ShowHideField();

    //… more code here
}

function ShowHideField() {
    // hide fields depending on yes/no questions …
}
```